# Map collection using stream is yielding strange compilation error

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, java-stream

I have this method:

```
 public void fields(TableField... s){
    // compilation error on next line
    Collection<String> fields = Arrays.asList(s).stream().map(v -> v.getValue());
    this.fields.addAll(fields);
  }
```

and TableField is simple just looks like:

```
class TableField {
  public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

but I am seeing this compilation error:

> Incompatible types. Required Collection but 'map' was inferred
>   to Stream: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that
>   Stream conforms to Collection

Answer (score 3):

`map` returns a transformed `Stream`. If you want a collection, you need to collect the Stream. E.g.:

```
Collection<String> fields =
    Arrays.asList(s).stream().map(v -> v.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @MrCholo you can reduce the number of letters by using `Arrays.stream(s)` instead of `Arrays.asList(s).stream()`. Further, you can omit the temporary local variable, `fields.addAll(Arrays.stream(s).map(v -> v.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()))`. Or the other way round, `Arrays.stream(s).forEachOrdered(v -> fields.add(v.getValue()));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `collect` the elements there and hence the type would be inferred:

```
Collection<String> fields = Arrays.stream(s) //  Arrays.asList(s).stream()
        .map(TableField::getValue) // map(v -> v.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or any other collection using 'Collectors.toCollection(<type>::new)'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using streams here. Just a traditional `for` loop would yield more succinct and much more performant code:

```
for (v : s) fields.add(v.getValue());
```

Comment: where's the fun in this? :)

Comment: it would be nice to call `this.fields.addAll(fields.map(v -> v.getValue());`